# Reactjs binding issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to request and receive data from signalR and bind data in ComponentDidMount in ReactJs
   I am using react framework to design a view with SignalR. I am able to connect to SignalR server and get data but if I required data to load on view appear I am not able to load data on ComponentDidMount.
If I request data on ComponentDidMount view is displaying blank.
On view load, I mentioned an icon (i) and clicking after view load then the data is binding.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Card, CardBody, CardFooter, CardHeader, Col, Row, Collapse, Fade } from 'reactstrap';
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {hub} from '../../SignalRHub';
class Users extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            userId:0,
            userName:'',
            usersList:[]
        };
    }
LoadUsersList()
{
    this.refs.child.userListRequest();
}
receiveUserList(userlist)
{
    this.setState({usersList: userlist});
}
render(){
    if(this.state.redirecttoUsers)
    {
        const route='/UsersInfo/'+this.state.userId;
        return (<Redirect to={route} />)
    }
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

            <div className="animated fadeIn">

                <SignalRHub ref="child" receiveUserList={this.receiveUserList.bind(this)} />

                <a href="#" className="card-header-action btn btn-setting" onClick={(event)=>this.LoadUsersList(event)}><i className="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>

                <Row>

                    {this.state.usersList.map((e, key) => {

                        return (

                            <Col className="col-3 .col-sm-3">

                                <div class="container">

                                    <Card className="border-primary crd" onClick={(event)=>this.userFingerInfoHandle(event,e)}>

                                        <CardHeader>

                                            {e.userName}

                                            <div className="card-header-actions middle upper">

                                                <a href="#" className="card-header-action icon btn btn-setting" onClick={(event)=>this.userFingerInfoHandle(event,e)}><i className="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>

                                                <a className="card-header-action img btn btn-setting" onClick={(event)=>this.userRemovalHandle(event,e.id)}><i className="fa fa-trash"></i></a>

                                            </div>

                                        </CardHeader>

                                        <CardBody align="center">

                                            {e.userName}

                                        </CardBody>

                                    </Card>

                                </div>

                            </Col>

                        )})

                    }

                </Row>

            </div>

        </form>

    );
};
}
   export default Users;
```

Answer (score 0):

update state in `componentDidMount` and reference all necessary data in `render` using `this.state`

The reason is simple.
`React` decide to update the DOM tree when either the `props` or `state` is changed by default, so only by changing either of them can you update the rendering unless you implement your own `shouldComponentUpdate`